# Can a link to the store be added?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, footer, shop

Can a link to the store be added to the bottom footer section of the SE sites...I presume it isn't there already because the store is in beta?

Would be great to have it there as with all the various little projects of SE (data, apps, area51, careers, blog, new se sites etc etc) I find I regularly check the footer to keep up to date with what's available...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll be adding this once the store is *officially* launched (it's in beta right now)

Comment: Is it out of Beta now?